# Export SQL Server 2005 query result to SQL INSERT statement?

Tags: sql-server-2005

Is there an easy way in SQL Server 2005 to export query results to a SQL INSERT statement? I'm thinking something along the lines of how you can use Database Explorer to script an existing stored procedure to a new query window.

We're looking to move some data from a dev DB to a production one; I know about linked servers but there's no way the DBA blackshirts will let us set that up.

A definitive, "Nope, you're boned," will suffice if it has to.

Edit: The table I want to insert into is not on the same database server. Without setting up a linked server, I can't do a select into.

Comment: Do you want/need to move the data all at once? Can you access both servers concurrently? Can/will there be some delay in writing data out and writing it back in? Is this a one-time task, or something you'll do regularly? There are many options, picking the one that fits your operational situation is the hard part.

Comment: @Philip Kelley: This is a one-off operation, but I can see similar events occurring. It's a relatively small (100 < X < 1000 rows) amount of application setup data. It was setup piecemeal in development and we're just looking for a shortcut to dump it to production. We can access both servers concurrently, but no one here has write access to production. We need to send something to the DBA's for them to run/use to give us our data.

Comment: In that case, I'd recommend BCP (even if it was my suggestion). You can create the files, test loading them on a separate dev server, then pass the files and "how to load" instructions to the DBAs. If or when it becomes a regular occurance, well, ok, I'd still do it that way, because I'd never create an automated dependency between a Production server and a Development server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another colleague of mine came up with a fun solution.

1) Copy query results grid to Excel. 
 2) Add the SQL commands and parentheses/commas/tick marks in columns between values.  
 3) Copy grid to a text editor. 
 4) Find/replace the stuff they needed to change/fix, including extra whitespace. 
 5) Send SQL to DBA's.

And voila! Several hundred rows queryized. It's ugly as sin but it took less time than looking for a 'sane' way to do it. This happens infrequently enough to suffice as a solution. I do appreciate everyone's suggestions, though - and I do intend to explore them further.

Edit: I am still looking for ideas! I like stuff to be cleaner than having Excel drop a steamer into Notepad++.

Answer (score 3):

If a script file is the only way to add data to your production server, it's easy enough to generate INSERT statements as the result set of a select statement.  It's boring and tedious, though, so if you have to do it often, I'd agree with the others who recomend third party tools.  If it's just a one-off, though, something like this should work.

```
select 'insert into MyTable (IntegerField, TextField)
values (' + convert(nvarchar(50),IntegerField) + ', ''' + TextField + ''');'
from MyTable
```

In SSMS, set "results to text" instead of "results to grid", and you'll get output that's easy to save in a text file and run as a script elsewhere; this, for example:

```
insert into MyTable (IntegerField, TextField)
values (1, 'a TextField value');
insert into MyTable (IntegerField, TextField)
values (23, 'another TextField value');
```

It's probably not very performant for large data sets, but given your restrictions it might be the easiest and simplest option.

Comment: That's pretty similar to what we ended up doing, except with Excel it's a little more scalable (easy enough to copy the same stuff to several thousand rows) without being all scary like using grep and regex.

Answer (score 2):

### another big one

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sysobjects WHERE xtype = 'P' AND name = 'spu_GenerateInsert')
BEGIN
     DROP PROCEDURE spu_GenerateInsert
END
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE spu_GenerateInsert
     @table varchar(128), -- used to specify the table to generate data for
     @generateGo bit = 0, -- used to allow GO statements to separate the insert statements
     @restriction varchar(1000) = '', -- used to allow the data set to be restricted, no need for the where clause but can use syntax as 'columna = 1'
     @producesingleinsert bit = 0, -- used to switch the ability to produce multiple insert statements (default) or one statement using UNION SELECT
     @debug bit = 0, -- used to allow debugging to be turned on to the stored procedure - in case of queries
     @GenerateOneLinePerColumn bit = 0, -- used to display the columns and data on separate lines
     @GenerateIdentityColumn bit = 1 -- used to prevent the identity columns from being scripted
AS
/*******************************************************************************
Original Author:    Keith E Kratochvil

This version:       Jane Dallaway

Updates at:         http://jane.dallaway.com/downloads/SQL/spu_generateInsert.sql

Documentation at:   http://jane.dallaway.com/blog/labels/spu_generateinsert.html

Date Created:       March 16, 2000

Description:        This procedure takes the data from a table and turns it into 
                    an insert statement.

CAUTION!!! If you run this on a large table be prepared to wait a while!

Modified:   add a comment here (date, who, comment)

Date        Name  Description
~~~~~~~     ~~~~~ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
07/11/03    Jane  Added a @generateGO parameter to allow selection
07/11/03    Jane  This procedure has an issue with NULLs....
07/11/03    Jane  Deal with Identities
07/11/03    Jane  Wrap all tablenames and columns with [ and ]
15/12/03    Jane  For DateTimes covert as style 1 - to allow for mm/dd/yyy
16/12/03    Jane  Get rid of rowcount
18/12/03    Jane  Prevent single field tables having that field displayed twice
06/07/04    Jane  Large money values get separeted with a comma - so specify convert
                  with 0 rather than 1         
31/05/05    Jane  Added default for GenerateGo and added ability to generate
                  Inserts for selected records based on the restriction
03/01/08    Jane  Updated to cope with text and ntext.  It converts to VARCHAR(8000) to allow quote escaping
                  Also copes with Nulls much better now.
07/01/08    Jane  Now handles guids
07/01/08    Jane  Forced collation to use database_default as was causing an error in some circumstances
15/01/08    Jane  Dave reported issue with image column types as a comment on my blog
                  http://jane.dallaway.com/blog/2007/11/generate-sql-insert-statement-from.html#c9038036788352783369
                  So, ensured that all column types either work, or replace with NULL and add warning
23/01/08    Jane  Ignore calculated columns.  Can't migrate the data, so remove from the INSERT
                  Implemented a suggestion from Jon Green - 4R Systems Inc left on my blog post at
                  http://jane.dallaway.com/blog/2007/11/generate-sql-insert-statement-from.html#c2055936172890486440
                  to allow a choice of separate insert statements or a single statement using the UNION SELECT syntax.
                  New parameter @producesingleinsert used.  When this is set to 0 it produces separate INSERT statements.
                  When set to 1 it produces a single statment using UNION SELECT
20/08/08 Jane     New parameter @GenerateOneLinePerColumn added as suggested by Christian via comment on my blog post at
                  http://jane.dallaway.com/blog/2007/11/generate-sql-insert-statement-from.html?showComment=1219174920000#c6992035307857457643
                  Also made all string variables varchar(max).  This means it no longer works on SQL 2000 - but to make it do so is just a case of
                  putting all varchar(max) to varchar(8000)
07/01/09 Jane     New parameter @GenerateIdentityColumns added as suggestion by James Bradshaw to enable identity columns to not be scripted
                  and therefore rely on the database to populate the identities from scratch
16/02/09 Jane     Continuation of work started on 20/08/08 - all remaining VARCHAR(8000)s removed and replaced with VARCHAR(max).  So, no longer
                  an issue with text columns unless it is SQL Server 2000, in which case this stored procedure will need to have been updated.  
16/04/09 Jane     Add checking to see if the table specified actually exists - user error on my case when using the procedure
17/04/09 Jane     Changed @tabledata to be nvarchar rather than varchar to allow for unicode                  
                  Added checking for data exceeding 8000 bytes and split the data based on CHAR(13) if this situation is seen.  
                  This won't resolve it in all cases, and if it doesn't then a warning is displayed at the bottom of the generated code
08/06/09 Jane     All strings are now output as N'<data>' rather than '<data>' to cope with extended character sets


Known Issues:     
     1) BLOBs can't be output

Usage:
     exec spu_GenerateInsert @table ='users', @generateGo=0, @restriction='columna = x', @producesingleinsert=0, @debug=0, @GenerateOneLinePerColumn=0, @GenerateIdentityColumn=0


Version:
     This version has been tested on SQL Server 2005.  To make this work on SQL Server 2000, replace all instances of VARCHAR(max) with VARCHAR(8000).  This will limit 
     the ability of export of text and XML columns to 8000 characters

*******************************************************************************/

--Variable declarations
DECLARE @InsertStmt varchar(max) -- change this to be (8000) for SQL Server 2000
DECLARE @Fields varchar(max) -- change this to be (8000) for SQL Server 2000
DECLARE @SelList varchar(max) -- change this to be (8000) for SQL Server 2000
DECLARE @Data varchar(max) -- change this to be (8000) for SQL Server 2000
DECLARE @ColName varchar(128)
DECLARE @IsChar tinyint
DECLARE @FldCounter int
DECLARE @TableData nvarchar(max) -- change this to be (8000) for SQL Server 2000

-- added by Jane - 07/11/03
DECLARE @bitIdentity BIT

-- added by Jane 03/01/08
DECLARE @bitHasEncounteredText BIT
SET @bitHasEncounteredText = 0

-- added by Jane 15/01/08
DECLARE @bitHasEncounteredImage BIT
SET @bitHasEncounteredImage = 0
DECLARE @bitHasEncounteredBinary BIT
SET @bitHasEncounteredBinary = 0
DECLARE @bitHasEncounteredXML BIT
SET @bitHasEncounteredXML = 0

-- added by Jane - 23/01/08
DECLARE @bitInsertStatementPrinted BIT
SET @bitInsertStatementPrinted = 0

-- added by Jane - 17/04/09 - To try and cope with bits of data which are greater than 8000 bytes
DECLARE @bitDataExceedMaxPrintLength BIT
SET @bitDataExceedMaxPrintLength = 0
DECLARE @cintMaximumSupportedPrintByteCount INT
SET @cintMaximumSupportedPrintByteCount = 8000 -- based on SQL Server 2005
DECLARE @statementToOutput NVARCHAR(max) -- change this to be (8000) for SQL Server 2000
DECLARE @NextCR INT -- used to split the output up into smaller chunks - look for carriage returns/line feeds and break into separate print statements
DECLARE @statementsToOutput TABLE (Id INT IDENTITY(1,1), singleStatement NVARCHAR (max) ) -- change this to be (8000) for SQL Server 2000
DECLARE @id INT
DECLARE @singleStatement NVARCHAR(max) -- change this to be (8000) for SQL Server 2000
DECLARE @loop INT

-- added by Jane - 16/12/03
SET NOCOUNT OFF

-- added by Jane - 16/04/09 - check for table existance
IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE TABLE_NAME = @table)
BEGIN

     -- added by Jane - 16/04/2009 - Show details of table being generated, and date/time
     PRINT REPLICATE('-', 37 + LEN(@table) + LEN(CONVERT(VARCHAR,GETDATE(),120)))          
     PRINT '-- Script generated for table ' + @table + ' on ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,GETDATE(),120) + ' --'
     PRINT REPLICATE('-', 37 + LEN(@table) + LEN(CONVERT(VARCHAR,GETDATE(),120)))

     -- added by Jane - 07/11/03
     SELECT @bitIdentity = OBJECTPROPERTY(OBJECT_ID(TABLE_NAME), 'TableHasIdentity')
     FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
     WHERE TABLE_Name =@table

     -- added by Jane - 03/01/08
     PRINT '-- ** Start of Inserts ** --'
     PRINT ''

     -- added by Jane - 07/11/03
     -- AND @GenerateIdentityColumn = 1 added by Jane - 07/01/09
     IF @bitIdentity = 1 AND @GenerateIdentityColumn = 1
     BEGIN
           PRINT 'SET IDENTITY_INSERT [' + @table + '] ON '
     END

     --initialize some of the variables
     -- updated by Jane 20/08/08 added one line per column functionality as per Christian's suggestion
     SELECT @InsertStmt = 'INSERT INTO [' + @Table + '] '+ CASE WHEN @GenerateOneLinePerColumn = 1 THEN CHAR(13) ELSE '' END + '(' + CASE WHEN @GenerateOneLinePerColumn = 1 THEN CHAR(13) ELSE '' END,
           @Fields = '',
           @Data = '',
           @SelList = 'SELECT ',
           @FldCounter = 0

     --create a cursor that loops through the fields in the table
     --and retrieves the column names and determines the delimiter type that the
     --field needs
     DECLARE CR_Table CURSOR FAST_FORWARD FOR

           SELECT COLUMN_NAME,
                  'IsChar' = CASE
                  WHEN DATA_TYPE in ('int', 'money', 'decimal', 'tinyint', 'smallint' ,'numeric', 'bit', 'bigint', 'smallmoney', 'float','timestamp') THEN 0
                  WHEN DATA_TYPE in ('char', 'varchar', 'nvarchar','uniqueidentifier', 'nchar') THEN 1
                  WHEN DATA_TYPE in ('datetime', 'smalldatetime') THEN 2
                  WHEN DATA_TYPE in ('text', 'ntext') THEN 3
                  WHEN DATA_TYPE in ('image') THEN 4 -- added by Jane - 15/01/08
                  WHEN DATA_TYPE in ('binary', 'varbinary') THEN 5 -- added by Jane - 15/01/08
                  WHEN DATA_TYPE in ('sql_variant') THEN 6 -- added by Jane - 15/01/08 - Force to be converted as varchars
                  WHEN DATA_TYPE in ('xml') THEN 7 -- added by Jane - 15/01/08
                  ELSE 9
           END
           FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS c WITH (NOLOCK)
           INNER JOIN syscolumns sc WITH (NOLOCK)
           ON c.COLUMN_NAME = sc.name
           INNER JOIN sysobjects so WITH (NOLOCK)
           ON sc.id = so.id
           AND so.name = c.TABLE_NAME
           WHERE table_name = @table
           AND DATA_TYPE <>'timestamp'
           AND sc.IsComputed = 0      
           AND 1 = 
               CASE @GenerateIdentityColumn 
               WHEN 1 -- When we want the identity columns to be generated, then always include the column
               THEN 1 
               ELSE 
                    CASE COLUMNPROPERTY(object_id(TABLE_NAME), COLUMN_NAME, 'IsIdentity') -- Check if the column has the property IsIdentity
                    WHEN 1 -- If it does
                    THEN 0 -- don't include this column
                    ELSE 1 -- otherwise include this column
                    END
               END
           ORDER BY ORDINAL_POSITION
           FOR READ ONLY
           OPEN CR_Table

           FETCH NEXT FROM CR_Table INTO @ColName, @IsChar

     WHILE (@@fetch_status <> -1)
     BEGIN

           IF @IsChar = 3
                  SET @bitHasEncounteredText = 1           

           -- added by Jane - 15/01/08
           IF @IsChar = 4
                  SET @bitHasEncounteredImage = 1
           IF @IsChar = 5
                  SET @bitHasEncounteredBinary = 1

           IF (@@fetch_status <> -2)
           BEGIN

                  -- Updated by Jane - 15/01/08 - cope with xml, image, binary, varbinary etc
                  -- Updated by Jane - 03/01/08 to cope with text and ntext - converts to VARCHAR(8000) to allow quote escaping
                  -- Special case for first field
                  IF @FldCounter = 0
                  BEGIN
                          SELECT @Fields =  @Fields + '[' + @ColName + ']' + ', '
                          -- Updated by Jane - 08/06/09 - prefix string with N to cope with extended character sets                          
                          SELECT @SelList =  CASE @IsChar
                                 WHEN 1 THEN @SelList +  ' ISNULL(''N'''''' + REPLACE(['+  @ColName + '],'''''''', '''''''''''') + '''''''' ,''NULL'')  ' + ' COLLATE database_default + '
                                 WHEN 2 THEN @SelList +  ' ISNULL(''N'''''' + CONVERT(varchar(20),[' + @ColName + ']) + '''''''',''NULL'') ' + ' COLLATE database_default + '
                                 WHEN 3 THEN @SelList +  ' ISNULL(''N'''''' + REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(max),['+  @ColName + ']),'''''''', '''''''''''')+  '''''''' ,''NULL'')  '+ ' COLLATE database_default + '
                                 WHEN 4 THEN @SelList + '''NULL''' + ' COLLATE database_default + '
                                 WHEN 5 THEN @SelList + '''NULL''' + ' COLLATE database_default + '
                                 WHEN 6 THEN @SelList +  ' ISNULL(''N'''''' + REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(max),['+  @ColName + ']),'''''''', '''''''''''')+  '''''''' ,''NULL'')  '+ ' COLLATE database_default + '
                                 WHEN 7 THEN @SelList +  ' ISNULL(''N'''''' + REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(max),['+  @ColName + ']),'''''''', '''''''''''')+  '''''''' ,''NULL'')  '+ ' COLLATE database_default + '
                                 ELSE @SelList + 'ISNULL(CONVERT(varchar(2000),['+@ColName + '],0),''NULL'')' + ' COLLATE database_default + '
                                 END
                          SELECT @FldCounter = @FldCounter + 1
                          SET @SelList = @Sellist
                          FETCH NEXT FROM CR_Table INTO @ColName, @IsChar
                  END

                  -- Updated by Jane - 15/01/08 - cope with xml, image, binary, varbinary etc
                  -- Updated by Jane - 03/01/08 to cope with NULL replacements           
                  -- Updated by Jane - 03/01/08 to cope with text and ntext - converts to VARCHAR(8000) to allow quote escaping
                  -- Updated by Jane - 18/12/03 to prevent single field tables having that field displayed twice
                  -- Updated by Jane - 20/08/08 to incorporate the @GenerateOneLinePerColumn parameter suggested by Christian
                  IF @@fetch_status <> -1
                  BEGIN
                          SELECT @Fields =  @Fields + '[' + @ColName + ']' + ', '
                          -- Updated by Jane - 08/06/09 - prefix string with N to cope with extended character sets
                          SELECT @SelList =  CASE @IsChar
                                 WHEN 1 THEN @SelList +  ''',''' + CASE WHEN @GenerateOneLinePerColumn = 1 THEN ' + CHAR(13) ' ELSE '' END + ' + ' +  ' ISNULL(''N'''''' + REPLACE(['+  @ColName + '],'''''''', '''''''''''' ) +  '''''''',''NULL'') ' + ' COLLATE database_default + '
                                 WHEN 2 THEN @SelList + ''',''' + CASE WHEN @GenerateOneLinePerColumn = 1 THEN  ' + CHAR(13) ' ELSE '' END + ' + '  +  'ISNULL(''N'''''' + CONVERT(varchar(20),['+ @ColName + '])+ '''''''',''NULL'') ' + ' COLLATE database_default + '
                                 WHEN 3 THEN @SelList +  ''',''' + CASE WHEN @GenerateOneLinePerColumn = 1 THEN ' + CHAR(13) ' ELSE '' END + ' + ' +  ' ISNULL(''N'''''' + REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(max),['+  @ColName + ']),'''''''', '''''''''''' )+  '''''''',''NULL'')  ' + ' COLLATE database_default + '
                                 WHEN 4 THEN @SelList + ''',''' + CASE WHEN @GenerateOneLinePerColumn = 1 THEN  ' + CHAR(13) ' ELSE '' END + ' + ' +  '''NULL''' + ' COLLATE database_default + '
                                 WHEN 5 THEN @SelList + ''',''' + CASE WHEN @GenerateOneLinePerColumn = 1 THEN  ' + CHAR(13) ' ELSE '' END + ' + ' +  '''NULL''' + ' COLLATE database_default + '
                                 WHEN 6 THEN @SelList + ''',''' + CASE WHEN @GenerateOneLinePerColumn = 1 THEN  ' + CHAR(13) ' ELSE '' END + ' + ' +   ' ISNULL(''N'''''' + REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(max),['+  @ColName + ']),'''''''', '''''''''''')+  '''''''' ,''NULL'')  '+ ' COLLATE database_default + '
                                 WHEN 7 THEN @SelList + ''',''' + CASE WHEN @GenerateOneLinePerColumn = 1 THEN  ' + CHAR(13) ' ELSE '' END + ' + ' +   ' ISNULL(''N'''''' + REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(max),['+  @ColName + ']),'''''''', '''''''''''')+  '''''''' ,''NULL'')  '+ ' COLLATE database_default + '
                                 ELSE @SelList  + ''',''' + CASE WHEN @GenerateOneLinePerColumn = 1 THEN  ' + CHAR(13) ' ELSE '' END + ' + ' + ' ISNULL(CONVERT(varchar(2000),['+@ColName + '],0),''NULL'')' + ' COLLATE database_default + '
                          END  
                  END
           END  

           FETCH NEXT FROM CR_Table INTO @ColName, @IsChar
     END

     CLOSE CR_Table
     DEALLOCATE CR_Table

     SELECT @Fields =  SUBSTRING(@Fields, 1,(len(@Fields)-1))

     SELECT @SelList =  SUBSTRING(@SelList, 1,(len(@SelList)-1))
     SELECT @SelList = @SelList + ' FROM ' + @table

     IF LEN(@restriction) > 0
     BEGIN
           SELECT @SelList = @SelList + ' WHERE ' + @restriction
     END

     -- updated by Jane 20/08/08 added one line per column functionality as per Christian's suggestion
     SELECT @InsertStmt = @InsertStmt + CASE WHEN @GenerateOneLinePerColumn = 1 THEN REPLACE(@Fields,', ',',' + CHAR(13)) ELSE @Fields END + CASE WHEN @GenerateOneLinePerColumn = 1 THEN CHAR(13) ELSE '' END + ')'

     --for debugging purposes...
     IF @Debug = 1
     BEGIN
           PRINT '*** DEBUG INFORMATION - THIS IS THE SELECT STATEMENT BEING RUN *** '
           PRINT @sellist
           PRINT '*** END DEBUG ***'
     END

     -- added by Jane - 16/12/03
     SET NOCOUNT ON

     --now we need to create and load the temp table that will hold the data
     --that we are going to generate into an insert statement

     CREATE TABLE #TheData (TableData VARCHAR(max)) -- change this to be (8000) for SQL Server 2000
     INSERT INTO #TheData (TableData) EXEC (@SelList)

     --Cursor through the data to generate the INSERT statement / VALUES/SELECT/UNION SELECT clause
     DECLARE CR_Data CURSOR FAST_FORWARD FOR SELECT TableData FROM #TheData FOR
     READ ONLY
     OPEN CR_Data
     FETCH NEXT FROM CR_Data INTO @TableData

           WHILE (@@fetch_status <> -1)
           BEGIN
                 IF (@@fetch_status <> -2)
                 BEGIN                                            

                       -- Updated by Jane 17/04/09 instead of printing at this point, store the output in a @statementToOutput variable.  This allows us to try and split it to 
                       -- to print within the 8000 byte limit imposed by the PRINT function         
                       -- Updated by Jane 23/01/08 after suggestion posted to blog at http://jane.dallaway.com/blog/2007/11/generate-sql-insert-statement-from.html#c2055936172890486440
                       IF (@producesingleinsert = 1 )
                              IF (@bitInsertStatementPrinted = 0)
                              BEGIN
                                    SET @statementToOutput = @InsertStmt + char(13) + 'SELECT ' + @TableData                                    
                                    SET @bitInsertStatementPrinted = 1
                              END
                              ELSE
                              BEGIN
                                    SET @statementToOutput = 'UNION SELECT ' + @TableData
                              END
                       ELSE
                       BEGIN
                              -- updated by Jane 20/08/08 added one line per column functionality as per Christian's suggestion
                              SET @statementToOutput =  @InsertStmt + CASE WHEN @GenerateOneLinePerColumn = 1 THEN CHAR(13) ELSE '' END + 'VALUES ' + + CASE WHEN @GenerateOneLinePerColumn = 1 THEN CHAR(13) ELSE '' END + '(' + CASE WHEN @GenerateOneLinePerColumn = 1 THEN CHAR(13) ELSE '' END + @TableData + CASE WHEN @GenerateOneLinePerColumn = 1 THEN CHAR(13) ELSE '' END + ')' + CHAR(13)
                       END

                       -- Added by Jane - 17/04/09 - check for length of @statementToOutput
                       -- if it exceeds the maximum length, then lets attempt to split it on CRs as these will be done via separate PRINT statements
                       IF DATALENGTH(@statementToOutput) > @cintMaximumSupportedPrintByteCount                                                                                                                     
                       BEGIN                                                      

                           -- Break the @statementToOutput based on CHAR(13) and put separate data values into @statementsToOutput table

                           -- Get rid of double line breaks
                           -- Replace CHAR(10) with CHAR(13)
                           SET @statementToOutput = REPLACE(@statementToOutput,CHAR(10),CHAR(13))
                           -- Replace CHAR(13)+CHAR(13) with CHAR(13)
                           SET @statementToOutput = REPLACE(@statementToOutput,CHAR(13)+CHAR(13),CHAR(13))

                           SET @NextCR = Charindex(CHAR(13),@statementToOutput)
                           WHILE @NextCR  > 0
                           BEGIN

                               INSERT INTO @statementsToOutput VALUES(LEFT(@statementToOutput,@NextCR - 1))

                               SET @statementToOutput = Right(@statementToOutput,Len(@statementToOutput) - @NextCR)
                               SET @NextCR = Charindex(CHAR(13),@statementToOutput)
                           END                                                     
                           INSERT INTO @statementsToOutput VALUES(@statementToOutput)                                                                                  

                           -- Output the statements line by line
                           SET @loop = 1
                           SET @id = -1

                           WHILE @loop = 1
                           BEGIN
                               SELECT TOP 1 @id = Id, @singleStatement = singlestatement
                               FROM @statementsToOutput
                               WHERE id > @id
                               ORDER BY Id

                               SET @loop = @@ROWCOUNT

                               IF @loop = 0
                                    BREAK

                               -- No guarantee that we still don't exceed the limits, but should have more of a chance of avoiding them
                               IF DATALENGTH(@singleStatement) > @cintMaximumSupportedPrintByteCount
                               BEGIN
                                    SET @bitDataExceedMaxPrintLength = 1
                                    SELECT @singleStatement                           
                               END

                               PRINT @singleStatement
                           END                                                     
                       END    
                       ELSE
                       BEGIN                    
                           -- Don't need to worry, we haven't exceeded the 8000 byte limit so just print it
                           PRINT @statementToOutput 
                       END

                       IF @generateGo = 1
                       BEGIN
                              PRINT 'GO'
                       END
                 END
                 FETCH NEXT FROM CR_Data INTO @TableData
           END
     CLOSE CR_Data
     DEALLOCATE CR_Data

     -- added by Jane - 07/11/03
     -- AND @GenerateIdentityColumn = 1 added by Jane - 07/01/09
     IF @bitIdentity = 1 AND @GenerateIdentityColumn = 1
     BEGIN
           PRINT 'SET IDENTITY_INSERT [' + @table + '] OFF '
     END

     -- added by Jane - 03/01/08
     PRINT '-- ** End of Inserts ** --'

     IF @bitHasEncounteredImage = 1
     BEGIN
           PRINT '-- ** WARNING: There is an image column in your table which has not been migrated - this has been replaced with NULL.  You will need to do this by hand.  Images are not supported by this script at this time.  ** --'
     END

     -- added by Jane - 15/01/08
     IF @bitHasEncounteredBinary = 1
     BEGIN
           PRINT '-- ** WARNING: There is a binary or varbinary column in your table which has not been migrated - this has been replaced with NULL.  You will need to do this by hand.  Binary and VarBinary are not supported by this script at this time.  ** --'
     END

     -- 16/02/09 - These checks are only required if the database is SQL Server 2000
     DECLARE @Version VARCHAR(100)
     SELECT @Version = @@VERSION
     IF PATINDEX('%8.00%',@Version) > 0
     BEGIN
          IF @bitHasEncounteredXML = 1
          BEGIN
                PRINT '-- ** WARNING: This will convert any ''xml'' data to be ''varchar(8000)'' ** --'
          END

          -- added by Jane - 03/01/08
          IF @bitHasEncounteredText = 1 
          BEGIN
                PRINT '-- ** WARNING: This will convert any ''text'' or ''ntext'' data to be ''varchar(8000)'' ** --'
          END
     END

     IF @bitDataExceedMaxPrintLength = 1
     BEGIN
          PRINT '-- ** WARNING: The data length for at least one row exceeds '+ CONVERT(VARCHAR(6),@cintMaximumSupportedPrintByteCount) + ' bytes.  The PRINT command is limited to ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(6),@cintMaximumSupportedPrintByteCount) + ' bytes (for more information see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176047.aspx).  Do not trust this data. ** --'
     END
END
ELSE
BEGIN

     -- added by Jane - 16/04/2009 - Warn user that table doesn't exist
     PRINT REPLICATE('-', 43 + LEN(@table))     
     PRINT '-- Table ' + @table + ' doesn''t exist on this database --'
     PRINT REPLICATE('-', 43 + LEN(@table))

END 
RETURN (0)

GO
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use SELECT INTO and INSERT INTO SELECT, both methods are shown [here](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/08/15/sql-server-insert-data-from-one-table-to-another-table-insert-into-select-select-into-table/)

Edit: maybe I misunderstood your question, and you want to generate INSERT scripts? In that case you could use tools like Apex SQL, SQL Delta or SQL Scripter.

Comment: I looked up SQL Scripter... not a big fan of trial software, but the graphical interface might suit some of my more commandline-averse colleagues. +1 for the suggestion

Answer (score 1):

The BCP utility suggests itself -- dump the data out into a file, then push it back in on the other server.

Comment: Looking into the BCP utility now. Looks promising... +1

Comment: Server won't grant access to the BCP util run locally... but it's still good to know about. Thanks!

Comment: That sounds like it's just a permissions issue?

Comment: "Just a permissions issue" is a death sentence here. Even if I could get permissions, it could take weeks.

Comment: Bummer. I hate when that happens.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at moving the data using [DTS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_Transformation_Services) (Data Transformation Services)? You can use this to export your data to file etc and then import it to your new database.

Answer (score 0):

iandisme,

We are in the same boat. All database changes must be scripted out and then applied to QA and Prod by someone else (segregation of duties.)  So we have a bunch of scripts that script out the insert statements or we just hand build them.

Comment: Yeah we've got that ISO "segregation of duties" dogma here. I really don't want production access ("Here, you hold this grenade."), but I have a sneaking suspicion that no one really looks at the scripts we send up.